# Where is strtof() in VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I can litterally not find which library/header this function is in, I've looked at so many examples of people using this function, but there are no results...
These are all the stuff I've included:

```
#include "Console.h"
#include "Direct3D9.h"
#include <string>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>
```

But still strtof comes up as "Error namespace "std" has no member "strtof""

What I'm trying to do:

```
 flValue = std::strtof( vszArgs.at( 1 ).c_str( ), NULL );
 pConVar->Set( flValue );
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof

Comment: It is still not part of std.
It says it should be part of cstdlib but when opening the document there is no strtof :/

Comment: As the reference mentions you need C99 standard capabilities of your c compiler fully supported and instrumented.

Comment: `strtof` was added to C by the 1999 standard, and to C++ by the 2011 standard. Just use `strtof` instead; it returns a `double` result which can easily be converted to `float`. You can add a range check if necessary. Or you might just want to use `double` rather than `float`.

Comment: Have you tried [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), the C++ version? It appears you have a `std::string` anyway, which it takes directly as an argument (no need to call `c_str()`).

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2012 does not implement `strtof`.

[Link to MSDN bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758053/missing-strtold-strtoll-strtoull-functions-from-stdlib-h) which includes a suggested workaround.

Comment: So is there anyway you can get them, maybe a raw function of how it works?

Comment: I could not find any links to how to implement strtof.

Comment: They suggest using the function `_atoldbl` instead

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) Include stdlib.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* strtof */
```

from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/

If that still doesn't work...

#### 2) Make sure your compiler is C++11 or newer

It's new as of C++11 so if you have an older compiler it won't work.

If that still doesn't work...

#### 3) Your compiler may just not support it

Visual C++ 2012 does not have full support for the C++11 standard. See the Visual Studio bug ["Missing strtof, strtold, strtoll, strtoull functions from stdlib.h"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758053/missing-strtold-strtoll-strtoull-functions-from-stdlib-h).

> We don't yet have those functions in the CRT. We will consider adding them to a future version of Visual C++.

Comment: Yes, but isn't in cstdlib for me, if I for example open the cstdlib document it is not there, any change anyone have a raw function for it?
These are the only avaiable strto functions inside the cstdlib for me:
using _CSTD strtod; using _CSTD strtol;
using _CSTD strtoul;

Comment: @Oskar see edit. If you're not seeing it then you must have a compiler older than C++11

Comment: I'm using Visual studio 2012, is that not new enough?

Comment: @OskarDahlberg _"is that not new enough?"_ We have Visual Studio 2015 now. 2012 is aged, let's say as good old wine, without any fresh tones. Same thing with GCC 4.8 or older versions BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in `cstdlib` when using C++11. The information can easily be found here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/?kw=strtof

My guess is that you aren't compiling using c++11.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2012